# How to force a download of a created file to a users computer c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, streamwriter

I am looking to allow a person to to export journal entries into a text file. I can create a file with all the data but rather strictly saving the file somewhere specific I want to allow a user to download and save the file where they want on their computer. How to I force a download of a file after I create it with StreamWriter. I currently have the following code:

```
string fileName = "Journal.txt";

        using (StreamWriter journalExport = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            foreach (JournalEntryView entry in journalEnteries)
            {
                //write each journal entery to file/document
                journalExport.WriteLine(entry.timestamp + " - " + entry.author + " (" + entry.authorRole + ")");
                journalExport.WriteLine(entry.text);
                journalExport.WriteLine("");
                journalExport.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
```

I am also trying to put this into an ActionResult and return the file.

**EDIT:**
The following code is my new current code and the direction I am looking to go in, but when I use an ActionLink to call this method, i just get redirected to a new page rather than downloading the file.

```
string fileName = "Journal.txt";
        string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentRoot"] + "\\" + id + "\\" + fileName;

        using (StreamWriter journalExport = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            foreach (JournalEntryView entry in journalEnteries)
            {
                //write each journal entery to file/document
                journalExport.WriteLine(entry.timestamp + " - " + entry.author + " (" + entry.authorRole + ")");
                journalExport.WriteLine(entry.text);
                journalExport.WriteLine("");
                journalExport.WriteLine("");
            }

        }

        byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Inline = true,
        };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        return File(fileData, contentType);
```

Comment: Did you look at `FileContentResult` and the `File()` method?

Comment: I have but I'm not sure how to use them to accomplish my needs

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    ...processing stuff...
    return File("/files/file.pdf", "application/pdf");
    //or
    return File("/files/file.pdf", "application/force-download", "donwloadname.pdf");
}
```

Comment: where does "files/file.pdf" and "downloadname.pdf" come from?

Comment: You can view the parameters that the `File` method allows, but in my example "/files/files.pdf" is the path to the pdf and "downloadname.pdf" is the name you want to give the pdf when the user downloads the file. Since I don't know your architecture the values will need to be customized to your application.

Comment: this still redirects my to a new page containing the file data, but not forcing the user a download of the file.